# Issue to display elements on top of a slider

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a jquery slider ([this one](http://www.slidesjs.com)). You can view my [test page here](http://goo.gl/eCliNf) 
The issue that I'm experiencing is that I'd like some div elements (touchpoints) to stay on top while in the background the slider slides the picture. Unfortunately for the moment it seems that my touch points are considered as slides (probably because they are wrapped into `<div ID="slides">`and therefore my DIV "touchPointContainer" slides as if it was a picture. What do I need to change in order for my touchpoints to always remain on top? Many thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="slides">
  <div id="touchPointContainer"> <a href="#" id="touchPoint1" class="touchPoint">
      <p class="initial">Changement</p>
      <p class="final">Le crtreement</p>
      </a> <a href="#" id="touchPoint2" class="touchPoint">
      <p class="initial">Rapidirtre fixé</p>
      </a> <a href="#" id="touchPoint3" class="touchPoint">
      <p class="initial">Orientation</p>
      <p class="final">Le crction</p>
      </a> <a href="#" id="touchPoint4" class="touchPoint">
      <p class="initial">Ressources</p>
      <p class="final">Le coacrtretences</p>
      </a> <a href="#" id="touchPoint5" class="touchPoint">
      <p class="initial">Créativité</p>
      <p class="final">Stimulatrtrer</p>
      </a> <a href="#" id="touchPoint6" class="touchPoint">
      <p class="initial">Autonomie</p>
      <p class="final">L’objecrtreret</p>
      </a> </div>

    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#touchPointContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
}
#touchPointContainer a { text-decoration: none }
.touchPoint {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #5bb6e7;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -moz-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -ms-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -o-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.touchPoint { display: table }
.touchPoint p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.touchPoint .final,
.touchPoint:hover .initial,
.touchPoint:active .initial { display: none }
.touchPoint .initial,
.touchPoint:hover .final,
.touchPoint:active .final { display: table-cell }
.touchPoint:hover,
.touchPoint:active {
    margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -moz-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -ms-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    -o-transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
    transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s;
}
#touchPoint1 {
    top: 260px;
    left: 140px;
}
#touchPoint2 {
    top: 240px;
    left: 440px;
}
#touchPoint3 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 670px;
}
#touchPoint4 {
    top: 90px;
    left: 480px;
}
#touchPoint5 {
    top: 390px;
    left: 300px;
}
#touchPoint6 {
    top: 370px;
    left: 670px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change position of the touch elements. top

```
position:absolute
```

and `top:20%`

with the right touch element at `left:9%`

try this in fire bug you will get an idea how to implement it in real :)
 Note : Change the styles of the  element fr touch ...

Image

[image: img new]

Edited Code for one constant touch point

change div wrapper code to

```
    <div id="fullwrapper"><a href="#" id="touchPoint1" class="touchPoint" style="
    z-index: 1111111;
">
      <p class="initial">Changement</p>
      <p class="final">Le crtreement</p>
      </a>
```

see the effect :)

new Image

[image: new touch point]

Comment: Thanks Anobik. Not sure to understand though. Do you mean changing the  touchpointcontainer from relative to absolute or adding "absolute" toTouchpoint1, Touchpoint2, etc? I tried both but without success... Many thanks

Comment: add 'absolute'  to both touch points and also top :20%  to both touchpoint. I hope the image is correct ?

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, what are you referring to by "both touch points?" Thanks

Comment: the arrows which are required to scroll the images ?? Image is the Image ok ?

Comment: OK, I thing we're not talking about the same thing :) There's no arrow no navigate between the images, I deactivated that.

Comment: and where do you e?xactly want them to be ? top in the sense ? won't they scroll

Comment: Want them at the same place but static on top of the slider (ie. want the slider images to slide but the touchpoint circles to always remain visible) - tks for your help